# Socket.io message sends but recipients do not receive it

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, backbone.js

I am in the process of making a chat application but have hit a problem. I submit a message and it gets saved into my database then sent through the channel to be picked up by everyone currently on the page. The issue I have is that the message gets saved and sent but not received by anybody apart from the person who sent it.

Here is my server socketio code:

```
var server = http.createServer( app ).listen( app.get( 'port' ) ),
    io = require( 'socket.io' ).listen( server );

//This is where we will listen and emit messages
io.sockets.on( 'connection', function( socket ) {
    console.log( 'Socket IO connected' );

    socket.on( 'send', function( data ) {

        console.log( data );

        var chat_model = require( './models/chat_model' );
        chat_model.add( data, send_through_channel );

        function send_through_channel( data ) {
            console.log( data );
            socket.emit( 'chat', data[0] );
        }
    });
});
```

Here is my client side socket.io code:

```
define( [ 'Backbone', '/socket.io/socket.io.js' ], function() {

    return Backbone.View.extend({

        socket: io.connect( 'http://192.168.0.38:3000' ),

        initialize: function() {

            //Fade out the success message
            $( '.js-success-float' ).fadeOut( 2000 );

            //Listen for new messages
            this.socket.on( 'chat', _.bind( function( data ) {
                console.log( data );
                this.append_message( data );
            }, this ) );
        }
    //More unrelated stuff below
```

Just wondered if anybody could point me in the right direction as to why the message is only being received by the person who sent it and not the rest of the users viewing the chat.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of sending message to particular receiver you should broadcast that message to all:
so not this

```
socket.emit( 'chat', data[0] );
```

but this:

```
io.sockets.emit( 'chat', data[0] );
```

Comment: Wow that was a simple fix. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here :

> socket.emit( 'chat', data[0] );

You are emitting data to the socket you received it from. In you case you should use :

> io.emit( 'chat', data[0] );
>
> or
>
> io.sockets.emit( 'chat', data[0] );

to send it to everyone, or :

> socket.broadcast.emit( 'chat', data[0] );

to send it to everyone except the sender.